# Php Difference between compile time and run time polymorphism

Tags: php

In case of php, what is the difference between runtime and compile time polymorphism

Comment: PHP is an interpreted language, so there is usually no compile time as such. What exactly are you talking about?

Comment: I wouldn't say there is compile time (ad hoc) polymorphism in PHP.

Comment: @Pekka: "PHP source code is compiled on-the-fly to an internal format," says Wikipedia. Most major language implementations are compiled, internally or externally... There just isn't always a resulting file.

Comment: Its not a homework question, just preparing for interview.

Comment: @Jesse true, but for most intents and purposes I would say this does not count as "compile time." Still, technically, you're right.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In php there is no such thing as compile-time polymorphism.

Compile-time polymorphism means that a function acts differently depending on type information that was known at compile-time. Since php is dynamically typed, it can't make any decisions based on types statically, so there can't be any kind of compile-time polymorphism.